# How to remove slice section marker from jfree chart

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, charts, jfreechart, jfreereport

i am using jfree chart in my report.I want to remove slice section from the piechart:
[image]

Also,i want to make it center the slice value and mentioned below the script which i am using currently:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot3D;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;

PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setSimpleLabels(true);
plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
plot.setOutlinePaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
plot.setLabelShadowPaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

can anyone suggest me how we can do ..

Comment: resolve by using plot.setSeparatorsVisible(false);

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 2):

Resolve the problem by using `plot.setSeparatorsVisible(false)`.